# How to concatenate two tags in phoenix framework?

Tags: phoenix-framework

What is the way to generate, let's say, two span elements inside a div element in a phoenix framework's view?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to do that it's possible to just use an array and pass it inside as the div tag's value like this:

```
def div_with_spans do
  content_tag :div, class: "test" do
    [
      content_tag(:span, "foo"),
      content_tag(:span, "bar")
    ]
  end
end
```

Comment: Just want to make answers to such common questions easier to find in google.

Comment: Obviously it would make sense to allow passing some parameters in the method, like options for tags or whatnot, but I guess it's not difficult to find out how to do that by yourself

Comment: I think you can too: `content_tag :div, [class: "test"], [span1, span2]`

Comment: I think it's worth noting that when `content_tag` is used to join, for example, two `inline-block` elements, there won't be an expected space between them (the one that you usually fix with negative margin, zero font size and whatnot)

Comment: Might also be worth noting the importance of the parentheses for the inner `content_tag` function calls to eliminate ambiguity.